# Is there a precedent for the use of this trope in Star Trek?

Tags: star-trek, trope, star-trek-beyond

I liked most of Star Trek Beyond, but I wasn't thrilled about the climax, when the crew

> used ancient RF tech and rock music to destroy advanced enemy ships

I didn't enjoy it because it's so implausible, but I'd be more comfortable if it was a nod to an event in the original timeline. So, has this trope been used before in Star Trek?

Comment: I guess if I'd be comfortable with it in that case, it's probably in character anyway and I should just be happy :-)

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GSbigjiKLoU

Comment: JJ Trek pays homage to things other than Trek more so than Trek and in particular comedy parodies of sci-fi stuff for the most part.

Comment: Star trek nope. But there was mars attacks where ancient music and technology defeated superior tech :)

Comment: "Implausible". I don't think that word means what you think it means.

Comment: @axelrod That's funny, but I'm going to defend myself anyway :-) I just meant that for most of the movie I could suspend my disbelief; for this scene I could not.

Comment: @z0r, I'm with you. Even if it "worked" why did they explode?

Comment: @Axelrod:   I accept "Implausible" -- in the sense that why would an alien technology just happen to be disrupted by the same technology used to broadcast audio signals on Earth centuries earlier.  Why would a particular form of music, that the writers liked, happen to be particularly disruptive.   It is an *implausible* plotline.

Comment: @ThePopMachine It specifically wasn't the same technology. The disruption signal was placed on the same frequency as the control signals. That the Beastie Boys have a "loud" musical style merely served as inspiration and a nice stylistic touch; any "noisy" (partially random, band-filling) signal can be used for such a jammer, as long as you're on the right frequency.

Comment: @Axelrod:   Why is it the same frequency as VHF?   Why are they using EM signals (radio) rather than subspace?   It is implausible.

Comment: @ThePopMachine Why wouldn't it be VHF? Subspace is EM via subspace -- for long distances. These ships, being close and intended to move together, wouldn't need it. Moreover, subspace communications rely on relays and thus can have variable latencies. It isn't anywhere near the implausibility of Space Whales.

Comment: @Axelrod:    Why **would** it be VHF?   That is exactly why it's implausible.

Comment: @ThePopMachine Because VHF is extremely effective at Line-of-sight communications and is extremely resistant to EM field interference. Also, its wavelength is small enough to not require large antennas and it's commonly used for satellite communication.

Comment: Because traveling back in time to get whales is _definitely_ more plausible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Not really, no.** The use of the track was obviously a nod to the [first film](https://youtu.be/MeRghYqi090?t=34s) in the reboot series but beyond that, there's been next to no contemporary music in any of the Star Trek shows or films.

> *It [Sabotage] is in the DNA of **this canon**. It was in the ’09 Trek, and we went
> through different iterations of the teaser and I wanted to make sure
> whatever here is using all the elements from the film. It’s been a
> part of this Kirk’s journey and so I felt it was very organic, and it
> will ultimately be in the finished film.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Justin Lin on ‘Star Trek Beyond’ Criticisms: “We Are Trying to Be Bold and Take Risks”](http://www.slashfilm.com/star-trek-beyond-criticisms/)</sup></sub>

Similarly, while the "*take down the swarm*" sequence bears some passing similarity to a scene in [DS9: Sacrifice of Angels](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Sacrifice_of_Angels_(episode)) (where the self-replicating minefield is destroyed), there doesn't seem to have been any *conscious* attempt to reference any prior Trek property.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It really couldn't be. The song blasted over the radio is from [1994](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sabotage_(song)). The original series was filmed from [1966 thru 1969](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek:_The_Original_Series) and the films from 1979 (The Motion Picture) to exactly 1994 (Generations).

There's a nod to the 2009 reboot, but definitely not to TOS.

I do like McCoy's comment about this being "classical music".

Comment: The "classical music" gag seemed like a nod to Futurama.

Comment: @Valorum - I'm sure the gag is older than futurama, but not sure where I heard it.

Answer (score 0):

It could be seen as a nod to the fact that the Borg are weak to conventional projectile weapons. This is shown in *Star Trek: First Contact*, when Picard uses the Holodeck (with safeties off) to get access to machine guns.

Similarly, the Borg seem to be vulnerable to bladed weapons, like the Klingon Bat'leth.

Both these and the music scene involve using older weapons to defeat an enemy that has tech that stops the higher tech weapons of the day.

Answer (score 0):

It might be a nod to *TNG: The Best of Both Worlds* where

> the crew destroys the attacking Borg Cube by sending an unauthorized command to regenerate via a hacked wireless data connection between Locutus (assimilated Picard) and the Cube.

It could also be a reference to *Mars Attacks* where

> the Martians are defeated by bad music broadcast via sound and radio.

which in turn is probably a reference to *The War of the Worlds* where

> the Martians are defeated by bacteria.